# PKCS#11 libraries from different software packages

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, pkcs#11

What is the difference between the PKCS#11 library provided by the libp11 and the OpenSC project. Are they mutually exclusive or do they depend on each other?

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki pages of the two projects stated:

https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki

> OpenSC implements the PKCS#11 API so applications supporting this API (such as Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird) can use it. On the card OpenSC implements the PKCS#15 standard and aims to be compatible with every software/card that does so, too.

https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11/wiki

> libp11 is a library implementing a thin layer on top of PKCS#11 API to make using PKCS#11 implementations easier.

So OpenSC is an implementation of PKCS#11 supporting PKCS#15 smartcards, while libp11 is a wrapper trying to make the PKCS#11 easier to use.

Comment: Right. The reason I'm asking is because I do not have libp11 installed, but smart card token access in working with the opensc-pkcs11.so lib provided by the opensc package only. That's why I'm wondering what kind of "thin layer" is provided by libp11 on top top of the PKCS#11 API.